# Push Notifications from 3rd party Alert api to individual device

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am creating an app that will get push notifications based on changes in flight status from the flightstats api.  A flight rule is created using a json request and then a deliver to which is the url of an https/http service that accepts post data is included in this request.  The part I am struggling with is how to get the alert delivered to the device that requested it.  Will any 3rd party services such as UrbanAirship work for this? If not how can I implement this?  Thanks for the help I am trying to wrap my head around this concept and how to implement it.

Comment: Have a look at UrbanAirship documents http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html, it walks through how to set it up

Comment: @Flexicoder I'm not sure if I am following will this allow the flightstats api to send a push notification to the device through urbanairship?

Comment: Does Flight Stats push information, looks to me like you have to query the information from them? If thats the case, you'll need some sort of server based system that records that a user is interested in a particular flight. Log that with there device information on your server. Periodically call flight stats from your server, for the latest info and if anything has changed use urban airship to push the message